# An exercise in the chapter of elliptic equations in Evans's PDE

Tags: partial-differential-equations, elliptic-equations

The following is from the 345th page of Evans 'Partial differential equations'.

> In the following exercises we assume the coefficients of the various PDE are smooth and satisfy the uniform ellipticity condition. Also $U \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ is always an open, bounded set, with smooth boundary.
>
> 1. Let
>      $$
>     L u = -\sum_{i,j=1}^n (a^{ij} u_{x_i})_{x_j} + cu.
>    $$
>      Prove that there exists a constant $\mu > 0$ such that the corresponding bilinear form $B[~,~]$ satisfies the hypotheses of the Lax-Milgram Theorem, provided
>      $$
>     c(x) \geq -\mu
>     \quad
>     (x \in U).
>    $$

In this excerpt, is the hypotheses of Lax-Milgram  condition? I mean that whether it is  needed to prove the $B[~,~]$ meets the hypotheses of Lax-Milgram.

If it is not needed, and I assume  $u\in L^2(U)$, it seemly be not connected with $x\in U$,and it seemly be connected with the $u\in L^2(U)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It just wants you to show coercivity (and boundedness) which are the two assumptions in the Lax Milgran theorem (other than bilinearity).

Comment: Whether it is needed to prove $c(x)\ge \mu~~~(x\in U)$ ?  And I don't know how to show it .Just two conditions of Lax-Milgran I can prove.

Comment: It is assumed that $c(x)\ge-\mu$

Comment: I get $B[u,u]\ge \theta\int_U|Du|^2dx+\int_Ucu^2dx$,but I can't get $B[u,u]\ge\beta||u||_{H_0^1}^2,(\beta>0)$

Comment: The main problem is how to show $\beta>0$

Comment: I'm assuming the function is in $H^1_0$, in which case by Poincare's inequality, there exists $C>0$ such that $$\int_U|Du|^2\ge C\int_U u^2,$$
so we get for $\gamma\in(0,1)$, $B[u,u]\ge\gamma\theta\int_U|Du|^2+(C(1-\gamma)\theta-\mu)\int_U u^2.$ Now we have criterion for the choice of $\mu$.